# What's a good way to describe the professional occupation of someone who is a street hustler, without using derogatory terms?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, contemporary-english, professions, class-based-usage

I am filling in a form for someone who basically does a variety of odd jobs to make a living, including reselling items, but "Sales" is not really an accurate way to describe their occupation. I am thinking of describing them as "self-employed" but that's a bit too vague.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: How about freelancer or independent contractor?

Comment: Is the person selling items on the street and/or itinerant? There's a difference between this and running a business from a private home reselling stuff. For example if you're just reselling merchandise from a location indoors you wouldn't really be a hawker, or huckster, or peddler.

Comment: @bookmanu Yeah, freelancer would probably come the closest to a good description without using condescending terms like "unskilled laborer"

Comment: @Zebrafish The person sells items on the street. I suppose "hawker" is also another word, but it brings to mind negative stereotypes.

Comment: @Dominique Independent Contractor _"carries more weight"_ than freelancer though.

Comment: @Dominique Haha, that's because most people going place to place or selling on the street are nuisances very often. Hawker is one of the more neutral terms, at least compared to huckster and peddler. I suppose travelling salesman/woman might soften the blow. Or street wares dealer. Or street vendor.

Comment: Even door-to-door salesmen can be seen to be a nuisance: http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/server300/7bbf7/products/535/images/616/no_hawkers__22882.1317275958.1280.1280.jpg

Comment: @Zebrafish Street wares vendor/street vendor is accurate and neutral. I also liked another word you used - "itinerant". The meaning isn't immediately obvious to most people but it's accurate.

Comment: street vendor I don't see a problem with it. Because by this term I can either picture a peddler, or a old man by the side of the road selling food. Many of the definitions for these words include "aggressive sales techniques", but I don't hear that in street vendor necessarily. For example a hot dog stand owner is found in the Wikipedia article for "street food". They are also called hawkers in that article, so hawker doesn't have to be negative.

Comment: What other types of work are included in "a variety of odd jobs"? Is it mostly selling, or is there some manual labor and other non-sales work?

Comment: A street vendor to me has a very specific meaning.  reselling items wouldn't really fit into the definition for me, unless you consider a hot dog vendor to be reselling second hand hot dogs.  Just my opinion, FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

Is your goal to help the individual in some way (for instance, to secure a job or benefits)? If so, I might avoid words like "hawker" or "peddler." (If not, those are fine choices.)

Is "purveyor of second-hand goods" too lengthy?

Comment: The person is part of a research study, so that's why I'm looking for something accurate yet neutral.  If it were a job application I'd definitely use something more professional-sounding.

"Purveyor of second-hand goods" sounds fine but I feel it's too specific for this case